# Android: Starting an intent inside of onCreate is causing an infinite loop / crash

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty new to Android/java, and have come up against my first head-scratcher.

I'm trying to conditionally change the starting view based on if a user is logged in (I've set is_logged_in already, here, to more simply illustrate the problem).

Many thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        boolean is_logged_in = false;

        if(is_logged_in) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        } else {
            menu_sign_up(); // How would I pass the View?
        }
    }

    // Doesn't work, at least when called inside of MainActivity's onCreate
    public void menu_sign_up(/* View view */) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignUp.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    // Example of a working method, at least when called from android:onClick in XML
    public void menu_sign_in(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignIn.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
    }
}

public class SignUp extends MainActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);
    }

    // ...
}
```

******* *Truncated Stack Trace Below* ********* (adb logcat *:W)

```
W/ActivityManager(19583): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{40953fd8 com.example.digitalkarmaeclipse/.SignUp}
W/ActivityManager(): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{}
W/ActivityManager(21900): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
W/ActivityManager(21900): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{40a23580 com.example.digitalkarmaeclipse/.MainActivity}
W/ActivityManager(21900): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{40a2c6f8 com.example.digitalkarmaeclipse/.SignUp}
W/ActivityManager(21900): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{40a30100 com.example.digitalkarmaeclipse/.SignUp}
W/ActivityManager(21900): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{40a338e8 com.example.digitalkarmaeclipse/.SignUp}
W/ActivityManager(21900): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{40a376e0 com.example.digitalkarmaeclipse/.SignUp}
```

Comment: Instead of using the intent, set the content view in the else part to the particular signup xml file

Comment: I tried this before, but I want to switch which class I am using the methods from. (in this case, SignUp.java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current app structure doesn't make a lot of sense.  Does `SignUp` have to be an Activity as well?  You could use an AlertDialog to do something similar.  If it does need to be an Activity then have it extend `Activity`, it doesn't make much sense to extend `HomeActivity` in this context.

I also don't like the idea of putting `setContentView()` in a logical statement.  onCreate() is only called when the Activity is created.  So if you start your `SignUp` Activity and then press the back button, there won't be a layout for your `HomeActivity`.

edit: And like Shark said it doesn't look like you have a way to pass the data from `SignUp` back to `HomeActivity`.  You should try to use `startActivityForResult()` and then use `setResult()` in `SignUp` to say whether it was successful or not.

Comment: I was going to write the setContentView thing as well.  That shouldn't be conditional at all.  Maybe setting the main layout to View.GONE by default and then showing it conditionally/OnResume makes a lot more sense.  But +1 because of the child activity extending the parent activity strangeness.

Comment: Yea.  I'm assuming that OP just wants a screen to pop up and prompt the user to sign up if they haven't.  There should definitely still be a base layout under that since if the user backs out of the sign up then the app is left in a weird state..

Comment: Yeah see my comment on Sharks answer... it is an infinite loop to me. It just doesn't get that far because of wake locks, which... thank god for those :)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer.  Chosen because you were correct the SignUp should not inherit from HomeActivity.  I will look into your other points as I restructure my app a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to let onCreate() finish, then move your new Activity to onResume() or onStart(); those get called as your activity is shown to the user instead of it still initializing (itself).

Also, it looks like you need to set up a

```
onLoginFinished(int result);
```

callback... either try running your login with startActivityForResult() and catching the result in onActivityResult()

OR ...

you make your own interface and once the other activity finishes it, it invokes the onLoginFinished(isOK) callback where you determine which screen to use.

Comment: +1 Exactly! As a third option you could run an AsyncTask that shows a dialog, checks the login status and then does the redirect to the signup page or shows the main layout.

Comment: somehow i don't think it'll be that clear to him. Look at the code posted, look at the logcat... I don't see traces of Log.wtf() there.

Comment: Yeah in all honesty it looks like an Infinite loop to me... MainActivity will always start SignUp which calls Super.OnCreate which is MainActivity... which will always start Signup... :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Glad to be aware of onResume/onStart. Turned out to be a simple inheritance issue/infinite loop as @Roloc pointed out.